# how to load the kendoMenu dynamically using dataSource or json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

I want to use kendoMenu.  I want to load the menu with parent and child fields dynamically.  Can anyone tell me how to load the kendoMenu dynamically using json/datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo Menu doesn't currently support the hierarchical data source. You can initialize it dynamically using a JSON object, like this:
http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/menu/overview#initialize-the-menu-using-json-data-object

Comment: I want to know what are the widgets supporting hierarchical data source as of now

Comment: $("#menu").kendoMenu({
    id: "id",
    dataSource: [{ text: json[0].menuName,
                  items: [{ text: json[0].childName },
                          { text: json[1].childName}]
                                  },
                           { text: json[1].menuName,
                              items: [{ text: json[0].childName },
                                { text: json[1].childName}]
                          },
                               { text: json[2].menuName}]
                    }); I have implemented in this way,Is it the only way to display the menu dynamically.

Comment: You can build your JSON on the server directly with text and items properties, then initialize with $("#menu").kendoMenu(myJSON), no need to reassign them like that.

Comment: can u please provide some sample code for build json on the server side

Answer (score 1):

This may be redundant to Bundyo's answer, but who doesn't like examples? :) This worked for me:

```
$.get("remoteMenu.php", function(data) {
    $("#menu").kendoMenu({
        dataSource: data
    });
});
```

Whereby, the "remoteMenu.php" returns a JSON object like:

```
[{"text":"Baseball","url":"requests","imageUrl":"http:\/\/demos.kendoui.com\/content\/shared\/icons\/sports\/baseball.png"},{"text":"Golf","url":"agencies","imageUrl":"http:\/\/demos.kendoui.com\/content\/shared\/icons\/sports\/golf.png"}]
```