# JQuery object with children causes undefined with populating Kendo menu

Tags: jquery, menu, kendo-ui, children

When loading a kendo menu from JQuery data source object when I hover over a menu item with children to have the drop down pop down I get the "undefined is not a function".

Let me start with saying the top level works as answered in this stackoverflow question:
[how to load the kendoMenu dynamically using dataSource or json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015939/how-to-load-the-kendomenu-dynamically-using-datasource-or-json)

I am learning jQuery and Kendo and just can't see what is missing...

I am sure I can iterate through my model object using jQuery and load the menu by "hand" however I don't think this is good practice and would be difficult to maintain.

My javascript is this(it works at the top level until I hover):

```
 $.get("/Home/getmenus", function (data) {
            $("#hmenu").kendoMenu({ dataSource: data })
            console.log(data);
        });
```

My object being returned from my API looks like this:

```
[{"id":13,"text":"File","url":"File URL","items":[{"id":5,"text":"Create New Ticket","url":"xx"},{"id":6,"text":"Create New Project","url":"222"}]},{"id":16,"text":"Edit","url":"Edit URL","items":[]}]
```

Again, I am new and studying and just need a little direction on this one please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several frustrating hours I found the solution and either there is a bug in one of the kendo js libraries or I was simply using the wrong one.

When I use this library:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.menu.min.js"></script>
```

I get the above error.  Even if I use a simple html ul/li/ul/li type of menu where the only javascript in my query is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#menu").kendoMenu();
});
```

Once I switched to using:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
```

This started working as you would expect.

So this is how I built my hierarchical menu with menu items being sourced from SQL via my api: (works great and so far no apparent additional performance hits e

```
<link href="~/Content/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.flat.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.data.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<ul id="hmenu"></ul>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get("/Home/getmenus", function (data) {
             hmenuelement = $("#hmenu");
            $.each(data, function (index, value)
            {
                hmenuelement.append("<li id='" + value.text + "'>" + value.text + "</li>")
                if (value.items.length > 0)
                {
                    var parentItem = $("#" + value.text);
                    parentItem.append("<ul id='" + value.text + index + "'></ul>");
                    childNode = $("#" + value.text + index);
                    $.each(value.items, function(index,value)
                    {
                        console.log(value);
                        childNode.append("<li>" + value.text + "</li>")
                    })
                }

            });
            (hmenuelement).kendoMenu();
        });
    });
</script>
```